# Always getting AppSync initial values when sending new values from iOS app

Tags: ios, pebble-watch

I am creating a Pebble companion app for an iOS application.  I have setup my AppSync with some initial values:

```
Tuplet initial_values[] = {
        TupletCString(SYNC_KEY_LANGUAGE, language),
        TupletCString(SYNC_KEY_TOTAL_AMOUNT, totalAmount),
        TupletCString(SYNC_KEY_TODAY_AMOUNT, todayAmount),
        TupletCString(SYNC_KEY_TRIP_NAME, tripName)
    };

    app_sync_init(&sync, sync_buffer, sizeof(sync_buffer), initial_values, 
                  ARRAY_LENGTH(initial_values), sync_tuple_changed_callback, 
                  sync_error_callback, NULL);
```

The problem is that when I push new data from my iPhone, the initial values are getting set to my text layers, instead of the data sent:

```
static void sync_tuple_changed_callback(const uint32_t key, const Tuple* new_tuple, const Tuple* old_tuple, void* context) {
    switch (key) {
        case SYNC_KEY_TRIP_NAME: {
            text_layer_set_text(tripNameLayer, new_tuple->value->cstring);
            layer_mark_dirty((Layer *)tripNameLayer);
        }
            break;
        case SYNC_KEY_TOTAL_AMOUNT: {
            text_layer_set_text(totalAmountLayer, new_tuple->value->cstring);
            layer_mark_dirty((Layer *)totalAmountLayer);
        }
            break;
        case SYNC_KEY_TODAY_AMOUNT: {
            text_layer_set_text(todayAmountLayer, new_tuple->value->cstring);
            layer_mark_dirty((Layer *)todayAmountLayer);
            //storeData(STORAGE_KEY_TODAY_AMOUNT, (char *)new_tuple->value->cstring);
        }
            break;
        case SYNC_KEY_LANGUAGE: {
            // DO NOTHING
        }
            break;
        default: {
            debugMessage("default case");
        }
            break;
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using from the iPhone side:

```
    NSDictionary *tripInfo = @{
                            @(SyncKeyTripName) : @"Denver",
                            @(SyncKeyLanguage) : @"en",
                            @(SyncKeyTotalAmount) : @"154.43",
                            @(SyncKeyTodayAmount) : @"23.50"
                          };

[self.watch appMessagesPushUpdate:tripInfo
                               onSent:^(PBWatch *watch, NSDictionary *update, NSError *error) {
                                   if (error) {
                                       NSLog(@"error sending update! %@", error);
                                   } else {
                                       NSLog(@"update: %@", update);
                                   }
                               }];
```

I have setup my watch buttons to clear out any values in those layers, this is how I know when the app is getting updates from the phone.

Why is AppSync continually using old data, instead of new data?

Comment: You should use `APP_LOG` to display the value that is being sent, to make sure it is indeed the new value.
You do not need to mark the layer dirty. `text_layer_set_layer` does it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this behavior is exhibited when calling the `app_sync_init` function more than once.  For some reason I had it being called twice when the application is being setup.  Once I removed the extraneous call, my callbacks contained the new data, not the initial.